# How to pass in variables to modules and components in angular2

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 to boostrap multiple UI modules if my webpage has the component selectors. I can't use a main app element and put all my content inside it. I want to however pass in variables to each components somehow.

My `init.ts`

```
System.import('@angular/platform-browser_dynamic').then(function(pbd) {
    const platform = pbd.platformBrowserDynamic();

    // I will put all my modules information here
    const modules = {
        'my-app': {
            selector: 'my-app',
            file: 'myapp',
            import: 'MyAppModule'
        }
    };

    // Loop through my settings object and look for modules/components to be bootstrapped if their selector exists on the current page
    for(var module in modules) {
        if(document.querySelectorAll(modules[module].selector).length > 0) {
            System.import('app/modules/' + modules[module].file)
                  .then(function(m) {
                      platform.bootstrapModule(m[modules[module].import]);
                  });
        }
    }
});
```

My `modules/myapp.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyAppComponent } from 'app/components/myapp';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [ MyAppComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ MyAppComponent ]
})
export class MyAppComponent {
   // maybe dynamically bootstrap components here
}
```

My `component/myapp.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'Hello World'
})
export class MyAppComponent {
    // or import data here
}
```

My final point would be to somehow be able to pass in element attributes to their components. I've tried using `ElementRef` that previously worked in angular2 components, but not anymore in 2.0.0 (not a release candidate anymore).

So I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in component/myapp.ts
The @Input() decorator defines a set of parameters that can be passed down from the component's parent. For example, we can modify the Hello component so that name can be provided by the parent.1

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'hello',
template: '<p>Hello, {{name}}</p>'
})
export class Hello {
@Input() name: string;
}
```